# Choosing good entropy $g$ and $p$ for a classic Diffie-Hellman Key exchange

Tags: diffie-hellman, implementation

When selecting $g$ and $p$ for the Diffie-Hellman modular exponentiation:

> $ s= g^x \bmod p $

Which pairs of $g$ and $p$ are considered good nowadays, are recommended by bibliography?

What I try to do is to write a simple Python script that chain calculates Diffie-Hellman Modular exponentiation:

```
def dh_public(secret):
    g=5;p=23 //@todo select better values

    return g**secret % p
```

For now, I have **REALLY POORLY** selected values but I want standardized and tested values for calculating a Diffie Hellman key exchange. As far as I know, both $g$ and $p$ should be primes.

Comment: There is no specific reason why $g$ must be a prime

Comment: $p$ should be a prime and $g$ a primitive root

Comment: IANA has a [registery](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-8) of them

Comment: @YoussefElHousni: $g$ needn't be a primitive root; it must generate a subgroup which has a size with a large prime factor

Comment: @poncho I agree. $g$ only needs to be of order multiple of a large enough prime.

Comment: DH _key(pair)_ needs entropy for security; parameters don't need any and often have very little. @DannyNiu+ also https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipsec-registry/ipsec-registry.xhtml#ipsec-registry-10 and https://www.iana.org/assignments/ikev2-parameters/ikev2-parameters.xhtml#ikev2-parameters-8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most commonly used values are in [this RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3526/?include_text=1); it includes groups that range from 1536 to 8192 bits; the size 2048 is actually the most common.

The properties of these groups include:

- The modulus is chosen using a 'nothing up my sleeve' method (and hence is unlikely to be specifically chosen to be especially vulnerable)
- The modulus has the high 32 bits and the low 32 bits all set; this can be useful for some modmul algorithms
- It has $g=2$; this can make the initial computation of $g^x \bmod p$ rather more efficient
- The order of the subgroup generated by $g$ is a prime of size $(p-1)/2$; a size which is quite sufficient for security

DannyNiu's reference to the IANA TLS groups (actually, the groups 256-260; the others are various elliptic curves which aren't what you are asking about) are another set; they're actually generated using the same procedure (and share the above properties), but are deliberately slightly different (to avoid potential factor-based style attacks against the original group)

Comment: Addition: the fragment `g**secret % p` must be changed to `pow(g, secret, p)` for the code to work with sizable arguments. Making it secure against side-channel attacks is uh, much harder.

Comment: Well I do not want  to mmake it ultra secure just to do some tests/research on chaining Diffie Hellman calculations on a Rachet tree Implementation.